# Can you play video from the iPod library?

Tags: video, ios4, ipod

Is it possible to play video from the iPod library in iOS4, or is it still restricted to audio?

I can't find any definite answers, but the SDK doesn't seem to allow video.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. Check the iPod Library Access Programming Guide, it says:

iPod library access applies only to audio-based media items. You cannot play video podcasts, movies, or television shows from the iPod library.