# Detecting music video from iPhone/Pad music library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, mpmediaquery, audio

Im using MPMediaQuery to search the library on a user's iPhone/Pad. Im able to return audio tracks but im unable to return any of the videos which are on the device. Apparently its not possible according to [this](http://webupon.com/audio/working-with-the-ipod-library/#ixzz1SlA3Ogdj) article but i fail to understand why this would be. If that is true, is there another way to retrive this information?

This is how im retrieving tracks

```
MPMediaQuery *queryTracksByArtist = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *pred = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"The Album Title" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];
[queryTracksByArtist addFilterPredicate:pred];
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [queryTracksByArtist items];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, As of now, you cannot access video with ipod library access. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781620/can-you-play-video-from-the-ipod-library).